Variable calculation changing by row in R
I have a data like:
library(dplyr)


set.seed(123)  
data <- data.frame(
  date = rep(1:3, each=3),
  grupo = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 3),
  x = runif(9, 10, 50),
  y = runif(9, 20, 100),
  z = runif(9, 5, 30)
)

# Convert group into factor
data$grupo <- as.factor(data$grupo)

# Order data 
data <- data %>% arrange(grupo, date)

I want the first observation of each row to be (1+original_value/100). However, starting from the second row I want the formula to be modified to first_modified_value*(1 + second_observed_value/100), the third new row will do: second_modified_value*(1 + third_observed_value/100).
I have generated the following formula, but I am not able to state that lag() should take the modified value, and not the lag(original value):
# Apply formula in each group for variables, x,y,z
dataaa <- data %>% 
  group_by(grupo) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(x, y, z), ~if_else(row_number() == 1, (1 + ./100), lag(.)*(1 + ./100))))


Any help?

The cumprod() function would appear to be the answer here as you are multiplying each value by the previous result:
dataaa <- data %>%
  group_by(grupo) %>%
  mutate(across(c(x, y, z), ~cumprod(1 + . / 100)))

dataaa
# A tibble: 9 × 5
# Groups:   grupo [3]
   date grupo     x     y     z
  <int> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 A      1.22  1.57  1.13
2     2 A      1.77  2.73  1.38
3     3 A      2.32  5.24  1.68
4     1 B      1.42  1.97  1.29
5     2 B      2.09  3.26  1.56
6     3 B      3.04  4.55  1.91
7     1 C      1.26  1.56  1.27
8     2 C      1.41  2.00  1.65
9     3 C      1.87  2.47  1.96


this is better than my answer; the Reduce approach only really adds value if your real problem is more complicated than simple cumulative product

You can use Reduce() here.. I make a small function f() that accepts a vector (x), and sets init to 1 + x[1[/100).  right and accumulate are set to F and T, respectively.
f <- \(x) Reduce(\(p,i) p*(1+x[i]/100),x=2:length(x), init=1+x[1]/100,F,T)
mutate(data, across(c(x,y,z),f),.by = grupo)

Output:
  date grupo        x        y        z
1    1     A 1.215031 1.565292 1.131980
2    2     A 1.765692 2.726827 1.384639
3    3     A 2.315249 5.235126 1.680850
4    1     B 1.415322 1.965467 1.288626
5    2     B 2.089280 3.258954 1.559401
6    3     B 3.044013 4.552335 1.913591
7    1     C 1.263591 1.562667 1.272385
8    2     C 1.412976 2.003870 1.652278
9    3     C 1.865939 2.472070 1.959628

